# jquery problem?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, fadein

i have this jquery problems i have had for days, im so new to this, so excuse my dumbness in this subject. thanks :))

html code:

```
<ul class="statuses">
<li id="set_23" class="message">
  // this is meant to increase everytime you click the vote_up just like stackoverflow 
  <span class="vote_count">27</span>
  <a href="#" class="vote_up"><img src="img/uparrow.png" /></a>
  <a href="#" class="vote_down"><img src="img/downarrow.png" /></a>

 </li>

</ul>
```

this is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#statuses').delegate('.vote_up', 'click', function() {
       //get the id
        var the_id = $(this).closest('.message').attr('id').split('_').pop();
        //the main ajax request
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "action=vote_up&id=" + the_id,
            url: "ajax/votes.php",
            success: function (msg) {
                  // fade in the new vote_count
                $(this).siblings("span.vote_count").html(msg).fadeIn();
                  // get the child <img> and set its src
                $(this).children("img").attr("src", "img/uparrowActive.png");
            }
        });
    });

});
```

EDIT: also the jquery fade.in and change of image src is not working, am i referencing the right span or class(the ajax request is working now)

Comment: ? sorry i updated the question, i forgot that i had  php varibale thier

Comment: where is the problem? what happens when you console.log(the_id) after you set it? what is the data being sent by the POST call?

Comment: just put your code on jsfiddle so people can see it run with one-click.

Comment: okay thanks @user257493, i will do that next time, thanks again

Comment: @getaway - Although you're title is poor, that isn't so bad. But you never actually asked a question in your post. Please make sure we do that so we don't have to guess what you are asking. It will help us help you. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing to jump-out:

```
<ul class="statuses">
```

and

```
$('#statuses')
```

... the # symbol in jQuery is the id-selector (same as CSS).  Since your `<ul>` is set to `class="statuses"` then you'll need to use the class-selector:

```
$('.statuses')
```

That alone will break all your jQuery

Comment: d'oh, can't believe I didn't see that.

Comment: lol thanks, the vote_count is working, which is brillant, :)), but the success function is not performing the fade.in and the change of image!! +upvote from me thhanks STW

Comment: np; usually it's the simple things like that

Comment: Or if there's only one `statuses` on the page (I'm guessing that's the case) it would be better to keep the `#statuses`, and change the element to `<ul id="statuses"> `. This will be a much faster lookup. Again, this is only if there's only meant to be one on the page.

Comment: everything works now thanks guys, but howcome when i click on vote button on the buttom of the page it takes me to the top of the page?

Comment: @getaway - Add `return false;` to the click handler, or add the `e` parameter to the handler: `.vote_up', 'click', function( e ) {...` and call [`e.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) inside the handler in order to prevent the default behavior of the `<a>` element from triggering.

Comment: cheers, you guys are like geniuses or what, how long have you been doing this ? :)) thank you very much @patrick uve been the heart of my problems!!!

Comment: @getaway - Keep at it. It'll start to feel natural before you know it. :o)

Answer (score 1):

From the jQuery docs:

> The beforeSend, error, dataFilter,
>   success and complete options all take
>   callback functions that are invoked at
>   the appropriate times. The this object
>   for all of them will be the object in
>   the context property passed to $.ajax
>   in the settings; if that was not
>   specified it will be a reference to
>   the Ajax settings themselves.

So, try adding `context: this` to your ajax request options.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
var the_id = $(this).closest('.message').attr('id').split('_').pop();
```

to this

```
var the_id = $(this).parents('.message').attr('id').replace('set_', '');
```

or alternatively

```
var the_id = $(this).parent().attr('id').replace('set_', '');
```

if you know that your link's parent element will always be `ul.message`.

Comment: Why the change? `.parents()` could return more than one result if there are nested `.message` elements, while `.closest()` will guarantee only the first ancestor with `.message`. And there's nothing wrong with `.split('_').pop()`.

Comment: Personal preference to be as explicit as possible.  `.closest()` introduces ambiguity and could potentially result in bad results if markup is changed (whereas being explicit requires JS to be conscious of the element hierarchy).

Comment: Also: keeping function calls to a minimum, especially when chaining, is never a bad idea.

Comment: Ok, personal preferences. I just couldn't figure out how your answer related to an issue in the question's code.